# Trouble getting button in custom uiview to respond to touch

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, delegates

So I have a custom UIView with a button in it, called the home button.  In other view controllers, this home button within this particular UIView works just fine.  In one particular view controller, however, the home button is non responsive to touches- the app acts as though the button is not even there.

```
class TemplateChooserViewController: UIViewController, HeaderViewDelegate {

...

  @IBOutlet weak var myHeader: HeaderView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    myHeader.delegate = self
    myHeader.Title.text = "Template Chooser"

... //All the rest of this function has been commented out and the home button still didn't work
 }

func homeButtonTapped()
{
    let home = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.first //code never reaches here
    self.navigationController?.popToViewController(home!, animated: false)
}
```

And the HeaderView file looks like:

```
protocol HeaderViewDelegate: class {
func homeButtonTapped()
func informationButtonTapped()
}


class HeaderView: UIView {

weak var delegate: HeaderViewDelegate?
@IBOutlet var view: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var Title: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var flameDecal: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var homeButton: UIButton!
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HeaderView", owner: self, options: nil)
    self.addSubview(self.view)
}

@IBAction func homeButtonTouched(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    delegate?.homeButtonTapped() //Code also doesn't reach here
}

@IBAction func infoButtonTouched(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.informationButtonTapped()
}
}
```

Keep in mind the code compiles fine, so I did have the infoButtonTouched function implemented, I just didn't see the point in showing it.  I have no idea why the button is unresponsive.  Any ideas on how to get the button to respond would be most helpful.  Thanks for your consideration of this matter.

Sincerely, 
Sean

Comment: make sure there are no invisible view that cover it, use the debug tab to see  all the layer on that screen

Comment: Check userInteractionEnabled, it must be "true"

Comment: While you add a view as subView you need to define frame, or autolayout constraints in your case both missing add any according to your project settings, it should work.

Comment: The problem probably is within the Xib or Storyboard that contains the `TemplateChooserViewController`. Is the non responsive button in there? Is it wired up correctly (ie. is it connected to your `@IBAction`)? Also, I think you wanted to implement some kind of Xib-referencing in your `HeaderView` but your implementation is not working. The line `Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HeaderView", owner: self, options: nil)` does nothing as you are not using the return value in any way.

Comment: @Tj3n Thanks for the tip- I had never used the debugger like that before.  However, having now used the debugger, I can say conclusively that nothing is above the button.

Comment: @AndrewVergunov I'm pretty sure custom UIViews don't need to be enabled in this manner.  I'm using this same custom UIView, HeaderView, in multiple other places and it works just find.  However, to humor you, I should mention that in desperation I tried adding that line.  It didn't help.

Comment: @iphonic Your tip is the one I don't understand.  I don't add the custom UIView as a subview- I add it inside the XCode Interface rather than programmatically.  The part about autolayout constraints- you'll need to elaborate.  I don't understand your meaning.

Comment: @mathiasnagler The unresponsive button is inside HeaderView (it's the home button inside HeaderView).  It is connected to TemplateChooserViewController via delegate.  This same home button does work correctly in other view controllers- it just doesn't work in TemplateChooserViewController.  Are you sure Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HeaderView", owner: self, options: nil) does nothing?  I was taught to use that line to get the information from the xib file to the class.  I think that's how it works, but I honestly haven't tried the class without it.  Regardless, I'm sure that is not the problem.

Comment: I'm quite sure that is in fact the problem but without seeing your storyboards and xibs it is impossible to pinpoint the issue. Also, I am sure on `loadNibNamed(_:owner:options)`. The methods loads a nib and then returns the contents as an array. You do *nothing* with those contents (you do not use the return value), thus the line is useless in your case. I suggest reading the documentation to said method: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsbundle/1618147-loadnibnamed?language=objc

Comment: Okay, but you aren't really helping me.  I don't care about useless lines of code in my code.  What I care about is making the software work.  This uiview WORKS FINE in every way possible in every other view controller, except the Template Chooser.  Why would the home button work in every other view controller except this one?  I don't understand.  PS I was taught how to create custom views on a youtube video- if the load nib function isn't necessary, it's their fault.  I just copied what I was taught.